# Location is not not shown on map

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to show a location on the map by retrieving Double values from Firebase realtime database. But when I start the maps activity the location is at 0.0,0.0 when there is a Double value stored in Firebase.

I have tried different codes to retrieve the location, but none of them show the correct location on the map.
Appreciate any help.

**MainActivity.Java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private
    RadioGroup route;
    public static final String ARG_FROM_MAIN = "arg";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations");
    public String someVariable;
    TextView numberbs;
    Button getLocationBtn;
    private Button btnSignOut;
    Button busb1;
    Button busb2;



    Button busb3;
    Button busb4;
    Button busb5;
    Button busb6;
    Button busb7;
    Button busb8;
    Button busb9;
    Button busb10;
    Button busb11;
    Button busb12;
    Button busb13;
    Button busb14;
    Button busb15;
    Button busb16;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        numberbs = findViewById(R.id.busnotext);
        btnSignOut = findViewById(R.id.signoutbtn);
        getLocationBtn = findViewById(R.id.getLocationBtn);


        numberbs = findViewById(R.id.busnotext);
        busb1 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn1);
        busb2 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn2);
        busb3 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn3);
        busb4 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn4);
        busb5 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn5);
        busb6 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn6);
        busb7 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn7);
        busb8 = findViewById(R.id.bustbtn8);
        busb9 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn9);
        busb10 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn10);
        busb11 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn11);
        busb12 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn12);
        busb13 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn13);
        busb14 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn14);
        busb15 = findViewById(R.id.bustbtn15);
        busb16 = findViewById(R.id.busbtn16);

        busb1.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb2.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb3.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb4.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb5.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb6.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb7.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb8.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb9.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb10.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb11.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb12.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb13.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb14.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb15.setOnClickListener(this);
        busb16.setOnClickListener(this);

        getLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("message", someVariable);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

/**
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Ref", someVariable);
        startActivity(intent);
 */
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.busbtn1:
               someVariable ="BUS1";
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 1");
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS1");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn2:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 2");
                someVariable ="BUS2";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS2");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn3:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 3");
                someVariable ="BUS3";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS3");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn4:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 4");
                someVariable ="BUS4";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS4");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn5:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 5");
                someVariable ="BUS5";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS5");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn6:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 6");
                someVariable ="BUS6";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS6");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn7:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 7");
                someVariable ="BUS7";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS7");
                break;
            case R.id.bustbtn8:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 8");
                someVariable ="BUS8";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS8");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn9:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 9");
                someVariable ="BUS9";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS9");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn10:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 10");
                someVariable ="BUS10";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS10");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn11:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 11");
                someVariable ="BUS11";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS11");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn12:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 12");
                someVariable ="BUS12";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS12");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn13:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 13");
                someVariable ="BUS13";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS13");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn14:
                someVariable ="BUS14";
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 14");
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS14");
                break;
            case R.id.bustbtn15:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 15");
                someVariable ="BUS15";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS15");
                break;
            case R.id.busbtn16:
                numberbs.setText("Selected: BUS 16");
                someVariable ="BUS16";
                mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child("BUS16");
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

**MapsActivity.Java**

```
package com.manavchordia.aplparent;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    //String value_latitude = "0";
   // String value_longitue = "0";
    Double longi = 0.0;
    Double lati = 0.0;
   // String message = "BUS1";
    Button Refreshh;
    Double latitude = 0.0;
    Double longitude = 0.0;
    String vali = "BUS1";
    String message = "BUS1";
    Button Backkk;

    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   // private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        vali = str;
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Locations").child(vali);
        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapm: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    latitude = snapm.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    longitude = snapm.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);

                    lati = latitude;
                    longi = longitude;

                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }



    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;



        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(vali));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        }
    }
}
```

**FirebaseDatabase: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiJ7M.png**
[FirebaseDatabase Image][1]

**Logcat:**

```
2019-08-18 23:26:33.138 906-916/? E/ActivityManager: Failed to schedule configuration change
    android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1177)
        at android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub$Proxy.scheduleTransaction(IApplicationThread.java:1815)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction.schedule(ClientTransaction.java:129)
        at com.android.server.am.ClientLifecycleManager.scheduleTransaction(ClientLifecycleManager.java:47)
        at com.android.server.am.ClientLifecycleManager.scheduleTransaction(ClientLifecycleManager.java:100)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateGlobalConfigurationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:25384)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateDisplayOverrideConfigurationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:25504)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateDisplayOverrideConfiguration(ActivityManagerService.java:25470)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.sendNewConfiguration(WindowManagerService.java:5033)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2599)
        at com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout(Session.java:245)
        at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:309)
        at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:165)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:752)
2019-08-18 23:26:33.138 906-916/? E/ActivityManager: Failed to schedule configuration change
    android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1177)
        at android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub$Proxy.scheduleTransaction(IApplicationThread.java:1815)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction.schedule(ClientTransaction.java:129)
        at com.android.server.am.ClientLifecycleManager.scheduleTransaction(ClientLifecycleManager.java:47)
        at com.android.server.am.ClientLifecycleManager.scheduleTransaction(ClientLifecycleManager.java:100)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateGlobalConfigurationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:25384)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateDisplayOverrideConfigurationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:25504)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateDisplayOverrideConfiguration(ActivityManagerService.java:25470)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.sendNewConfiguration(WindowManagerService.java:5033)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2599)
        at com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout(Session.java:245)
        at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:309)
        at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:165)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:752)

    cfey: UNAUTHENTICATED: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
        at cfeu.c(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):3)
        at sgt.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):79)
        at bbrg.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):9)
        at bbqz.run(Unknown Source:3)
        at bbpv.run(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):1)
        at soj.b(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):33)
        at soj.run(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at suh.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-08-18 23:26:36.597 23168-23168/? E/MS_LookUpHelper: Lookup exception.
2019-08-18 23:26:36.598 23168-23168/? E/MS_LookUpHelper: Failure while querying in batches.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Err: 17
        at bblk.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):76)
        at com.google.android.libraries.matchstick.contacts.sync.TachystickSyncChimeraService.onStartCommand(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):4)
        at ehk.onStartCommand(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):1)
        at qkj.onStartCommand(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):3)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3858)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:209)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6954)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-08-18 23:26:36.599 23168-24728/? E/MS_ServerQueryProvider: Failed to get server result.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Err: 17
        at bqqe.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):3)
        at bqqe.get(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):24)
        at bqqo.get(Unknown Source:0)
        at bbla.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):5)
        at bbkd.call(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at soj.b(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):33)
        at soj.run(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):18)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at suh.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Err: 17
        at bblk.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):76)
        at com.google.android.libraries.matchstick.contacts.sync.TachystickSyncChimeraService.onStartCommand(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):4)
        at ehk.onStartCommand(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):1)
        at qkj.onStartCommand(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):3)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3858)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:209)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6954)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

 aoqx: 29504: Null server response, http status code 401: 3
        at aotx.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):442)
        at aotx.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):504)
        at aotc.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):14)
        at aosz.b(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):10)
        at aosa.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):92)
        at aosa.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):75)
        at aaiz.run(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):19)
        at blon.run(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):2)
        at soj.b(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):33)
        at soj.run(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at suh.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-08-18 23:26:49.569 23155-23318/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=RegisterSyncOperationCall
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=Null server response, http status code 401: 3, resolution=null}]
        at aosa.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):100)
        at aosa.a(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):75)
        at aaiz.run(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):19)
        at blon.run(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):2)
        at soj.b(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):33)
        at soj.run(:com.google.android.gms@18385037@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at suh.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiJ7M.png
```

Comment: Are you using android O?

Comment: no I'm using Android Pie on a OnePlus 6

Comment: There are some changes for post 7.0 devices, I have added an answer hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

From android O you should start your service like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
}
else {
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

In your case `FreshchatService`.

Comment: No I don't use FreshchatService

Comment: From what I saw from your logs, you are using this service, or do you have it from Freshchat SDK? Then fill bug for them, that their SDK contains this issue.

Comment: I've updated my Logcat please have a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> For pre-8.0 devices, you have to just use startService(), but for post-7.0 devices, you have to use startForgroundService(). Here is a
>   sample for code to start service.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, ServedService.class));
    } else {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ServedService.class));
}
```

Comment: But I'm starting a activity

Answer (score 0):

you are not refreshing map when the location from the firebase is fetched .. you are just storing the location in a global variable

also your code is wrong to fetch latitude and longitude . below code should work

```
for (DataSnapshot snapm: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     String key = snapm.getKey();
     if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("latitude")){
        lati=snapm.getValue(Double.class);
     }
     if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("longitude")){
        longi=snapm.getValue(Double.class);
     }
}    

 // add this code here
 if (mMap != null) {
   LatLng sydney = new LatLng(lati,longi);
   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(vali));
   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate through the `DataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method, you can simply use only the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference busRef = rootRef.child("Locations").child("BUS11");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot ds) {
        double lat = ds.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        double lng = ds.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("BUS11"));
        Log.d(TAG, lat + ", " + lng);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
busRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result of using this code will be a marker added on you map and the following line printed ot in the logcat:

```
13.0641221, 80.2500812
```